# How to use url_for in js file with https in jinja2 python flask?

Tags: python, templates, flask

How can I use flask's `url_for` to link a `JavaScript` file with https in jinja2 python flask?

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/typed.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}">
</script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/vendor/owl.carousel2/owl.carousel.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/vendor/modal-video/js/modal-video.min.js') }}"></script>
```

[image: image of error]

Comment: There is no `filename` argument for starters. What is the error message? Did you read the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sub-folders `js` and `vendor` in `static` folder, do this:

Instead of:

```py
# filename starts with a slash (/)
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/typed.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Do:

```py
# filename has no slash (/)
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/typed.min.js') }}"></script>
```

It applies to the the other links too.